# Subset of $ \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} $ is closed

Tags: general-topology

I have some questions regarding this exercise: Let $C=\{s \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}: s(n+1) \leq 2s(n), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I need to show that $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ under the product topology.

So what I am trying to do is to look at the complement of $C$ and try to show that it is open by taking a function $t \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \setminus C$ and coming up with an open set $U = \prod_{k=1}^\infty U_k $ but now I'm not sure how to define the finite $U_k$'s that are not equal to $\mathbb{R}$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this along exactly the lines you were thinking.

If $t \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \setminus C,$ then there is some $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t(n_0+1)\gt 2\,t(n_0).$

Let $\varepsilon=\dfrac{t(n_0+1)-2\,t(n_0)}{3},$ which is positive.

Define $U_{n_0}$ to be the open set $(-\infty,t(n_0)+\varepsilon),$ and define $U_{n_0+1}$ to be the open set $(t(n_0+1)-\varepsilon,\infty).$

Set $U_k=\mathbb{R}$ for all $k$ other than $n_0$ and $n_0+1.$

Then $t\in \prod_k U_k,$ and, for any $s\in \prod_k U_k,$ we have

\begin{align}
s(n+1)-2s(n)&\gt t(n_0+1)-\varepsilon-2(t(n_0)+\varepsilon)
\\&=t(n_0+1)-2\,t(n_0)-3\varepsilon
\\&=0,
\end{align}

so that $\prod_k U_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \setminus C.$

Answer (score 5):

The maps $v_n:\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R$ given by $v_n(s)=s(n)$ are all continuous. Your set is $$C=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(2v_{n}-v_{n+1})^{-1}\left([0,\infty)\right)$$

Which must be closed.